# Billingsley Exercise 8.8 (Markov Chains)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am studying from Billingsley and would like some hints on the following exercise.

> Suppose $S = \{0,1,2,...\}$, $p_{00} = 1,$ and $f_{i0} > 0$ for all $i$.
>
> Here, $S$ represents the state space, $$f_{ij} = P_{i} \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [X_{n} = j]\right)$$ and   $P_{i}(A) = P[A\mid X_{0} = i]$.
>
> Show that $$P_{i}\left(\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty}[X_{n} = j \;\; \text{i.o.}]\right) = 0$$ for all $i$.

Comment: Good for you giving the citation.  Could you explain the "i.o." notation?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It is short for "infinitely often". In other words, $\{X_n = j \;\;\text{i.o.}\} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n = j\}$.

Comment: @Math1000 for infinitely many $n$?  OK, got it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I believe that is not the case.  Notice that each $X_{n} = j$ infinitely often in the measurable set, and thus each $X_{n}$ hits $j$ infinitely many times, not just for each n.  Thus, it is best to think as $\{A_{n} \; i.o.\} = \limsup A_{n} = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \cup_{n = m}^{\infty} A_{n} = \{ \omega$ that are in infinitely many $A_{n} \}$.  This is my understanding at least.

Comment: @Did: No, I don't think you can.  Imagine a chain that moves from $i$ to either $0$ or $i+1$, so $p_{i,0} + p_{i,i+1}=1$.  If $p_{i,0} \to 0$ sufficiently fast, there may be a positive probability that we never jump to 0.  Of course, in that case, the chain drifts off to infinity, so the claim that no state is visited infinitely often is still true.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, I was misleading, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by

$$\tau_j := \inf\{n \geq 1; X_n = j\}$$

the hitting time and define, iteratively,

$$\tau_j^k := \inf\{n > \tau_j^{k-1}; X_n = j\}$$

for $k \geq 2$.

---

**Hints:**

1. It suffices to show that $P_i(X_n = j$ i.o.$)=0$ for all $j \geq 1$.
2. Show that $$P_j(\tau_0<\infty) \leq P_j\left( \left\{ X_n = j \, \,
   \text{i.o.} \right\}^c \right).$$ Conclude that $P_j(X_n = j \,
   \text{infinitely often})<1$.
3. Set $p:= P_j(\tau_j< \infty)$. Using the (strong) Markov property,
   show that $$P_j(X_n = j \, \text{for at least $k$ times}) = P_j(\tau_j^k
   <\infty) = p^k.$$ Conclude that $$P_j(X_n = j \, \text{infinitely
   often}) \in \{0,1\}$$ depending whether $p<0$ or $p=1$.
4. Combine step 2+3 to deduce that $P_j(X_n = j \, \text{infinitely
   often}) =0$.
5. By the Markov property, $$P_i(X_n = j \, \text{infinitely often})
   \leq P_j(X_n = j \, \text{infinitely often}).$$ Now the claim follows
   from step 3.

Comment: I think I have it.  I just can't show the first part of step 2.

Comment: @DRich Sorry, I made a mistake there. See my edited answer...

Comment: Thanks so much!  (a little late on that I know hehe)